# follower() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a followers/following system in my Django app. But get this error:  `follower() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile'`

But in my views.py where the argument is missing as the program says is not actually missing.

views.py

```
def followers(request, profile):
    data = serialize("json", Follow.objects.all(), cls="LazyEncoder")
    return render(request, "network/follow.html", {
        "profile": User.objects.get(username=profile),
        "json": JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    })
```

follow model in models.py

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rel_from_set")
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rel_to_set")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)

# Add following field to User dynamically
User.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Follow, related_name="followers", symmetrical=False))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("profile/<str:profile>", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("followers", views.followers, name="follower"),

]
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/followers

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['network',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dziug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dziug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /followers
Exception Value: followers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile'
```

As of right now, I only have this one follower path and still trying to figure out how to do followers system properly

Comment: share your urls

Comment: can you add the whole traceback? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the request didn't include a profile, which could as a request `params`. in the following definition:

```py
def followers(request, profile):
```

anyone who is using such definition shall provide both `request` & `profile`. so what happens is that your `urls.py` file would match this definition to the requested url. django will provide you with `request` object. however, `profile` should be something like `/followers/the_real_profile_is_me/`

A request to `/articles/2005/03/` would match the third entry in the list. Django would call the function `views.month_archive(request, year=2005, month=3)`

more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/